# Angular Material change mat-form-field theme

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I'm trying yo change  text color with no success. 
In component scss file i put the folowing:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$auth-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo, 50, 100);
$auth-accent: mat-palette($mat-indigo, 50, 100);
$auth-warn: mat-palette($mat-pink, 400, 500);
$auth-theme: mat-dark-theme($auth-primary, $auth-accent, $auth-warn);

@include mat-form-field-theme($auth-theme); // Form-Field theme
@include mat-input-theme($auth-theme);      // Input Theme
```

This snippet change with success the colors of label, underline, error text and fill. But the input text/icons colors still the default grey.

Is there one way to change the colors of input text, icon, and button from grey to white  **using material sass properties/mixins or functions** ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this code.

```
$mat-indigo: (
    50 : #f9e4e5,
    100 : #f0bcbf,
    200 : #e79094,
    300 : #dd6369,
    400 : #d54149,
    500 : #ce2029,
    600 : #c91c24,
    700 : #c2181f,
    800 : #bc1319,
    900 : #b00b0f,
    A100 : #ffdddd,
    A200 : #ffaaab,
    A400 : #ff7779,
    A700 : #ff5d5f,
  contrast: (
    50 : #000000,
    100 : #000000,
    200 : #000000,
    300 : #000000,
    400 : #ffffff,
    500 : #ffffff,
    600 : #ffffff,
    700 : #ffffff,
    800 : #ffffff,
    900 : #ffffff,
    A100 : #000000,
    A200 : #000000,
    A400 : #000000,
    A700 : #000000,
  )
);
$mat-indigo: (
  50 : #e7e7e7,
  100 : #c2c2c2,
  200 : #999999,
  300 : #707070,
  400 : #525252,
  500 : #333333,
  600 : #2e2e2e,
  700 : #272727,
  800 : #202020,
  900 : #141414,
  A100 : #ef6e6e,
  A200 : #ea4040,
  A400 : #f60000,
  A700 : #dd0000,
  contrast: (
      50 : #000000,
      100 : #000000,
      200 : #000000,
      300 : #ffffff,
      400 : #ffffff,
      500 : #ffffff,
      600 : #ffffff,
      700 : #ffffff,
      800 : #ffffff,
      900 : #ffffff,
      A100 : #000000,
      A200 : #ffffff,
      A400 : #ffffff,
      A700 : #ffffff,
  )
);
```

then it will work already. The problem is you dont set your `$mat-indigo`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-light-blue, A200, A100, A400);

$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$candy-app-theme: mat-dark-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);
```

so that there is no problem of turning the inputs black, even in dark environments, you just need to change the display mode of the theme:

dark mode:

```
$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($auth-primary, $auth-accent, $auth-warn);
```

light mode:

```
$candy-app-themee: mat-light-theme($auth-primary, $auth-accent, $auth-warn);
```

just switch between the theme itself between

```
mat-dark-theme
```

and

```
mat-light-theme
```